# PHP function passing variable

Tags: php, function

I have a function call rsstotime

```
function rsstotime($rss_time) { // convert to unix timestamp}
```

if I call it like this:

```
$time = rsstotime('Wed, 05 Aug 2015 11:21:00 BST');
//returns 1438773660 the correct timestamp
```

If I call it like this

```
$pub = 'Wed, 05 Aug 2015 11:21:00 BST';
$time = rsstotime('$pub');
//returns 946598400
```

I'm guessing the string $pub is being converted instead.  I thought I could pass a variable into a function like that?

Comment: Have you tried passing `$pub` without single quotes: `$time = rsstotime($pub);`?

Comment: My bet is @JonnyHenly should submit that as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you use single quotes the variables are not used. If you use double quotes they are.

But why use string literals when you can just use the variable like `func($var)`?

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to use quotes '' in variable name, just use like this:

```
$time = rsstotime($pub);
```